# Remove gap between 2 divs

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using material css for a small project, specifically the cards. I have 2 [cards](http://materializecss.com/cards.html) in my page and want to remove the space between them. I thought I would be fairly trivial but cant seem to apply any `css` to my content. Heres my code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="card-panel blue accent-3">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title white-text"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true">
                            </i> title</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="second">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="card-panel white blue-text">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">report 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">report 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">report 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">report 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">report 5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #e7e6ef;
    }
    .row {
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: 50%;
    }
    #second {
        margin-top: 0; !important;
    }
</style>
```

How it looks:

[image: matcss]

However I cant seem to remove the gap between the 2  cards nor center them. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try setting the `<ul>`'s `margin` to 0. Because the default margin of `<ul>` is 1em (top and bottom).

Comment: FYi... `margin-top: 0 !important;` <-- you had an extra semicolon in there, which is incorrect.

Comment: can you clearify me that in blue section and white section space remove or other space remove

Answer (score 3):

you must set margin for .row and .card-panel :

```
.row{
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.card-panel {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcpoxj9c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.card-panel { margin: 0; }` (This class has preset margins that you need to override)

Comment: I did try it. No matter which div I select, there always exists a gap between the 2 cards.

Comment: Use the browser's developer tools to check which element/s has/have margins and and `margin: 0;` to that/those.

Answer (score 0):

Add css to your `row` divs **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcpoxj9c/)**

```
.row{ 
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

Also you are mixing `bootstrap` classes with the `materialize.css` classes please try to use only one plugin.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed
          margin-top: 0; !important; 
is wrong. Replace with 
          margin-top: 0 !important;

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).